# How to manually load all classes inside rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How to load & get collection of all active-record models used inside rails app.
It should give classes from gems, plugins as well as subclasses having active-record base in parent hierarchy.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.collect(&:name)
```

gives me list but its only after all classes gets loaded.
Is there any way to load all classes inside rails app manually ?

Comment: I already exercised with a lot many ways http://www.funonrails.com/2012/01/get-models-list-inside-rails-app.html but haven't came up with clean conclusion. After reading tadman's answer, am realized that it wont possible :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with Ruby is that "all classes" is a somewhat difficult thing to ascertain. Some of them may be generated dynamically and conditionally.

Sometimes you can just load what's present in `app/models`:

```
Dir.glob(File.expand_path("app/models/*.rb", Rails.root)).each do |model_file|
  require model_file
end
```

If there's other locations that may contain models you'll need to include those, too.

You might have dependencies, though, and that can preclude model A from loading before model B. This is why the autoloader is used by default and things just aren't loaded in.

The only reliable way to get them all loaded is to somehow exercise them all at least once.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. Till date was under impression that there must be certain way to load classes used inside rails app but its not the case and autoloader loads classes whenever required.

Answer (score 2):

Getting model list based upon db tables -

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.collect{|t| t.singularize.camelize.constantize rescue nil}.compact
```

Comment: hopefully above wont work because its not always necessary to have model associated with every db table.